# JavaScript Closure question: why is the second call to outerFn creating a new instance of outerVar?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I'm making headway on understanding closures, but I don't understand how the following example even creates a closure. I'll quote a passage from 'Learning jQuery', page 392, and what the author says about the example.

The author says that because "readyVar persists between calls to the function", we can see a closure is involved. But, to me, readyVar persists between calls to innerFn simply because the anonymous function has not yet finished executing. Once the anonymous function finishes, there will be no references to readyVar and it will be garbage collected. So where is the closure? I'm under the impression that a closure involves a variable being referenceable in a scope outside of that scope in which the variable was defined. But I don't see that here.

Is the author saying that anytime an inner function references a value defined in an outer function, a closure is created? That can't be what he's saying, can it?

The rest of this message is a quotation from the aforementioned book.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var readyVar = 0;
  function innerFn() {
    readyVar++;
    $('#example-9').print('readyVar = ' + readyVar);
  }
  innerFn();
  innerFn();
});
```

This looks like many of our earlier examples, except that in this case, the outer function is the callback passed to $(document).ready(). Since innerFn() is defined inside of it, and refers to readyVar which is in the scope of the callback function, innerFn() and its environment create a closure. We can see this by noting that the value of readyVar persists between calls to the function:
readyVar = 1
readyVar = 2

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the author is saying.

Comment: Is the title of your question wrong?  It sounds like the title of a previous question and not what you're asking about here.

Comment: If that is exactly what he is saying, then does the following create a closure when it is run?

    function A() {
      var t=1;
      function B() {
        t=2;
      };
    }

I thought a closure was something else. Namely, I thought a closure was where a variable becomes referenceable in a scope outside the scope in which the variable was defined. That's not the case in the above example, and it's not the case in the original example I quoted.

jfriend00, yes, it is wrong--sorry. It is the title of my previous question. I forgot to change the title when I posted the current question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the duration of the `$(document).ready` function, all it's local variables are active and hold their values and any code in that function or any embedded functions can reference them.  While one could describe this as a function closure, this is more just how local variables work in a function.

If, inside the `$(document).ready`, there was an embedded function that stored a reference somewhere (like a click handler), then a lasting function closure would be established and the value of `readyVar` would last as long as any embedded references last.  It's essentially garbage collection.  As long as something outside the function loop holds a reference to something inside the loop, the loop stays alive.  At the point where the loop is done executing and nothing outside the loop holds any embedded function references to things inside the loop, the loop gets garbage collected and goes away.

Since there are not embedded function references in what you have now, it will get garbage collected (e.g. destroyed and freed) when it finishes executing.

Now, if you modified it to add a click handler like this, then you now have a lasting reference to a function inside the `$(document).ready` function with  the click handler function.  Since that lives on, even after the `$(document).ready` loop has finished executing, it will not be garbage collected and will live on as a function closure.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var readyVar = 0;
  function innerFn() {
    readyVar++;
    $('#example-9').print('readyVar = ' + readyVar);
  }
  innerFn();
  innerFn();
  $("#content").click(function(){  // external reference to within this function
      alert(readyVar);
  });
});
```

I sense from your question that you're confusing local variables with function closures.  The two are related, but not the same thing.  Local variables are always available for the lifetime of the function.  The lifetime of the function is the time it's executing except when a reference to a closure within it causes it to last longer than that.

You might find this helpful: http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't clear on the definition of a closure, but am now. They simply occur *whenever* an inner function references a free variable x, ie, a variable that is neither a parameter of the inner function nor a variable whose scope is limited to the inner function's scope. Which, in itself, is not exotic. But if the inner function makes x referenceable outside of the scope it had, x will live on as long as it is referenceable in that wider scope.

Comment: Not quite, but close.  The closure stays alive when an inner function is referenced outside the scope of the function (like the event handler in my example).  Having an outside reference to a variable will keep that specific variable alive, but won't keep the whole function closure alive or any of the other variables that themselves aren't referenced from the outside.  Individual variables can be kept alive on their own, but an inner function has to have it's whole context (e.g. closure) in order to stay alive.